# Сводный вывод без join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица `a` c полями :

```
 _id | name | code 
-----+------+------
```

есть таблица `b` c полями:

```
 clientId | itemId | itemType 
----------+--------+----------
```

Помогите составить запрос, (без джойнов) где выведутся все значения из `a` и динамический столбец `foo` с значением `true/false`, который будет отображать, наличие записи из таблицы `b`, столбцы для сравнения `a._id = b.itemId`.

Полагаю надо использовать что-то вроде `select _id, 'foo' as "i_am_foo" from a;` для добавления динамического столбца и
`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE true) as "foo";`

Comment: "where true" -> "where b.itemId = a._id"

Comment: `select a.*,EXISTS(SELECT FROM b WHERE b.itemId = a._id) as "foo" from a`

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    a.*, -- все поля из а
    exists (select 1 from b where b.itemId = a._id) foo 
from a;
```

[PostgreSQL - выполнить запрос online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=93ba242b065faf41b5ba0b1948e5f35e&php_version=null&sql_version=psql14)